# Concatenate Fields of a Linked Table

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

I have generated a MS Access database from Sharepoint. All the tables in the Access DB are linked to the Sharepoint lists and any changes I make in Access to the fields are written back into the Sharepoint online. There is a field that I would like to be a derived field that is a concatenation of two other fields. However, since the table itself is a linked table, it doesn't let me do any type of query or lookup directly in the table itself.

I tried going into the Linked Table's Design View and modifying the Data Type to be a query or lookup, but I get a "Sharepoint Foundation Does not support this type of data change" I assume whatever data type the field inherited from the Sharepoint list is going to be what it is and I cannot change it.

How do I create this concatenation and still maintain the ability of writing back to the Sharepoint list whenever I update that data in the Access tables?

Comment: [Calculated fields belong in queries, not tables.](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on the Access side just take the Linked table and create a Query...just select all the fields of the table and at the end enter a new expression :

```
CustomConcat: [Field1] & [Field2]
```

Comment: Thanks for tip. What can I do if one of these fields is pulling from a combobox? Using [Field1] & [Field2] in the Query Design View would return the index value of the combobox instead of the text value.

Comment: Just get the text of the combobox

Comment: It seems the operators of [Field1].Value, [Field1].Text, and also [Field1].Column(1) don't work in the Query design window expression window. What script can return the text from this Sharepoint combo box?